# Webpack: put each entry point to its separate file

Tags: webpack, sass

I have a nodejs project.  I'm new to this, so I ask for a bit of patience. I'd like my .scss files to be transpiled to .css and have it extracted from `[name].scss`, to `[name].css`.

I have configured webpack to look for every *.scss file, with `glob.sync(...)` and that part works. I also configured the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to extract the output to a `.css` file.

Still, for whatever reason, I get only 1 output file (strictly speaking 2, because I get a main.js file as well), called `main.css`, with all the .scss filed merged into it.

I looked for all kinds of tutorials, but I'm not really understanding the concept here, so that's why I ask here as well. My webpack configuration is as follows:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync("./src/**/*.scss"),
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|otf)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                            context: 'src'
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                }, {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () {
                            return [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts']
    }
    mode: "production",
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: I worked out the main cause of this "error", which is if I add a simple array to entry, it will be put into a map, where the key is `main`. The output file name is the key of this map, which as you might have guessed, is `main`. So I need to find a function extracting the filename without extension from the path

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution:

As I said in my comment:  the main cause of this "error", which is if I add a simple array to entry, it will be put into a map, where the key is main. The output file name is the key of this map, which as you might have guessed, is main. So I need to find a function extracting the filename without the extension from the path.

I wrote this function:

```
const getFilename = (path) => {
    const myRegexp = /(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+)*(?:\/((?:[^\/])+)\..*)+$/g;
    let result = myRegexp.exec(path)[1];
    console.log("input: " + path + ", output: " + result);
    return result;
};
```

It takes in the whole path and returns the filename, without the extension. Now some of you JS gurus might finch at this, but I'm not a JS guy mainly. I just want a set and forget method for scss and minimal typescript compilation in maven.

this way, the `entry:` part of my config became as follows:

```
entry: () => {
    const files = glob.sync("{./src/**/*.ts,./src/**/*.scss}");

    return files.reduce((acc, val) => {
        let filename = getFilename(val);
        if(acc[filename] === undefined) {
            acc[filename] = [];
        }
        acc[filename].push(val);
        return acc;
    }, {});
},
```